# How to return the results from a Mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im studying Mysqli at the moment.
But i have a problem about how to return a resultset from a mysqli prepared statement.
I have the following code in Loginclass.php:

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db->getCon());

    $stmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_username` = ? AND `user_password` = ?');
        $user_username = $this->_user_name;
        $user_password = $this->_password;
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_username, $user_password);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    else {
        $this->setPass(true);
        return $result;
    }
```

Now i want in login.php to do the following with the returning $result var:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$_SESSION['login']['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all because of `$db->getCon()` method name :)

Looks like you don't understand logic of operators - read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Try this code:

```
//$stmt is object, which can be returned by prepare method
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_username` = ? AND `user_password` = ?');
$user_username = $this->_user_name;
$user_password = $this->_password;
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_username, $user_password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);  //instead of $stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();

if (empty($result))
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    $this->setPass(true);
    return $result;
}
```